# image format / type changes when i try to perform a 'save image as'?

Tags: html

Why does the image and image path differ in formats when i do save image as in site?

please check below link

https://veerle.duoh.com/images/portfolio/_normal/teamleader-illu-hero-2.png

When i see image and its path on website, it shows png format, but when i want to save the image, it shows up like webp format in chrome. How does this happen.  how can the type of the image change?

Comment: you can specify multiple img src  e,g, `<img srcset=””>`

Comment: this is her actual code : `<figure class="project-image hero">
<img src="https://veerle.duoh.com/images/portfolio/teamleader-illu-hero-2.png" alt="Illustration library for Teamleader" class="hero" srcset="https://veerle.duoh.com/images/portfolio/_small/teamleader-illu-hero-2.png 800w, https://veerle.duoh.com/images/portfolio/_normal/teamleader-illu-hero-2.png 1400w" sizes="(max-width: 1400px) 100vw, (min-width: 1400px) 100vw">
</figure>`.  Are you sure you don't have some plugin of some sort?  ]

Comment: Thank you for reply...
when i saw image and image path on website show png but when i save image as show like webp in chrom.do not use multiple images formate 


I want to information of when i did save image as ,that time show image path PNG,
https://veerle.duoh.com/images/portfolio/_normal/teamleader-illu-hero-2.png

but when i did save image as in local that time saw webp image format.

how it will be do image format set on dempand format ?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a `content-disposition` in the header/response of the actual resource:

[image]

As per the docs of MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

As a response header for the main bodySection

The first parameter in the HTTP context is either inline (default value, indicating it can be displayed inside the Web page, or as the Web page) or attachment (indicating it should be downloaded; most browsers presenting a 'Save as' dialog, prefilled with the value of the filename parameters if present).

```
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"
```

Comment: Thank you,
when i saw image and image path on website show png but when i save image as show like webp in chrom.do not use multiple images formate 


I want to information of when i did save image as ,that time show image path PNG,
https://veerle.duoh.com/images/portfolio/_normal/teamleader-illu-hero-2.png

but when i did save image as in local that time saw webp image format.

how it will be do image format set on dempand format ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to say, but it comes down to the fact that the browser interprets and obeys the content-disposition header the server sends. Pls check closely the picture.  Request is file.png. Respone disposition is file.webp.  the browser will always save in webp i guess, in contrary to what it shows in some parts of the UI

Comment: ok,thank you for reply. nly i tried to call. show in path PNG format, when i did save image as that time show webp. in that site not kept webp how that possible in site?
i hope you understand.

Comment: please refer this document:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition.  maybe you can use google translate.  it's all explained there (better than me at least i guess:)